# Deleting Google Image Search History

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, google-search, search-history

On my Android device, the Samsung Galaxy S, I frequently use Google and its search functions. Now have I noticed that I cannot seem to delete the Image Search history. When I search something using the regular search I can easily delete that search afterwards. But an earlier search in the Google Image Search does not seem to be possible..

Am I wrong? I have already tried things like deleting the search history through Google, which did not help, and deleting the history on my browser app, which also did not help.

If anyone has some helpful information it will be appreciated!

Kind Regards, Floris

**EDIT:** This has **not** been solved yet. The issue still remains. I can delete the history of the regular Google website, the Browser on my Phone and the history of the Google Widget. Yet *after* doing a search through the Google Widget you come to a Google page with the results, if you search again on *that* page then the autocomplete comes on with all my old history. Still searching a solution.

**EDIT 2:** This question is not relevant to me anymore. Due to some other issues I had to go back to factory settings which deleted most of my data. I cannot accept any answer as I am not able to check whether that answers works..

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases:

1. You are logged in your google account on your device browser
2. You are not logged in

In case 1, go to www.google.com, scroll down and click on "settings" at the bottom. You'll get to a page which gives you the option of wiping your search history

In case 2, go to www.google.com, start typing something in the search box, you'll see in the autocomplete the option to wipe your search results.

What Matthew suggested wipes the search history of your device not on google's servers.

You have to do both if you wanna clear everything.

Comment: I've tried it and the history on the Google website was gone, which is good. But, when using the search on my Google Widget on my phone I can still see my history. I do not mean the history of the widget, but the history you see after you have searched something and then move on to search a new thing. It seems likes eventhough it is Google, it is not the actual Google website.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the cache of the Google Search app (setup -> apps -> manage apps -> Google Search)?

Answer (score 1):

Go To Settings, More at the top right of the screen, then click on storage, then click applications, find the Google Maps application in the list and click it.  Once inside click Clear data and Clear cache.  This should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

History in the browser is your history of visited sites.  Saved form information (your searches) is different and separate.  Hit the `Clear form data` option in the browser settings.

Comment: This did not work, I cleared everything I could in my browser settings, yet the Google Images Search history still remained.

Comment: That's bizarre.